# Laravel Excel/PHP Excel: Import, modify, download

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I'm struggeling with [Laravel-Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) (Laravel Package of PHPExcel).

I'm not able to modify a file. My file has one workbook (called template). I want to load the document, modify it and let the user download it:

```
Excel::selectSheets('template') -> load($source, function($file)
{

}) -> download('xls');
```

Code above works so far. But I don't get how to fill cells. I don't want to export an eloquent model directly, I need to follow a certain structure. The Excel file was not created by me, I just need to fill it with data.

So how can I for example fill cell A2 with the firstname of the current user?

I search for something like

```
Excel::cell('A2') -> content = $user -> name;
```

This is just an example of what I want to achive, this is not working code!

Thanks,
LuMa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel-Excel runs off of PHPExcel, and you can run native PHPExcel methods on the objects exposed by Laravel-Excel.

From the docs, to get the cell: http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#cells

```
\Excel::create('Document', function($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet', function($sheet) {
        $sheet->cell('A2', function($cell) {
            $cell->setValue('this is the cell value.');
        });
    });
})->download('xls');
```

And, here is a screenshot of the $cell instance showing what else can be called on it:

[image: Kint dump of the $cell instance]

Comment: @Laravelian Hey bro. scnshot gives nice functionality, What is this ? any app or library

Answer (score 2):

I use that in this way:

```
Excel::load('template_orden_compra.xls', function($doc){
   $sheet = $doc->getActiveSheet();
   $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $user->name);
})
->store('xls', storage_path('Excel'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native PHP Excel functions:

```
Excel::load('file.xls', function($excel)
{
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');
}) -> download('xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for multiple sheets.

```
$somevalue = array('abc', 'xyz');

Excel::load('file.xlsx', function($file) use($somevalue) {
   $file->sheet( 'sheetName', function ($sheet) use($somevalue){
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', $somevalue);
   });
})->export('xlsx');
```